# Implementation of Queue<E> interface

Tags: java, arrays, generics, interface

I am having trouble understanding the nuances of generics, interfaces, and arrays and how to use them together. I have an assignment for an intermediate Java class. The assignment is as follows:

- Create a generic class SimpleQueue that implements Queue
- Use a constructor to initialize an array with 5 slots.
- Use of ArrayList not allowed
- We must be able to increase the size of the array if it gets filled

The problem I'm having is the with the initialization of the array. Here's the code I have:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

public class SimpleQueue<E> implements Queue<E>{

    private E myQueue[];

    //Constructor with no arguments.
    public SimpleQueue() {
        myQueue = new [5];
        System.out.println("A queue with length " + myQueue.length + " was created.");
    }
}
```

Eclipse complains by saying that we can't create a generic array. I've managed to get it to work by doing this:

```
private Object myQueue[] = Object[5];
```

...but I feel like this defeats the purpose of using generics. Am I misunderstanding the use of generics? Pointers would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code I'm using to test my generic class as I'm working:

```
public class SimpleQueueTester {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SimpleQueue<String> myStringQueue = new SimpleQueue<>();
        SimpleQueue<Integer> myIntegerQueue = new SimpleQueue<>();
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: Please don't think I want my homework done for me. I'm just stuck at this point and I figured this would be the best place to ask. Thanks!

**Edit**: I took some of your suggestions and now my code looks like this:

```
public class SimpleQueue<E> implements Queue<E>{

    private E[] myQueue;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //Constructor with no arguments.
    public SimpleQueue() {

        //This was changed. What does (E[]) do exactly?            
        this.myQueue = (E[]) new Object[5];
        System.out.println("A queue with length " + this.myQueue.length + " was created.");
    }
}
```

Thank you for you suggestions! You guys are awesome.

Comment: Try `myQueue = (E[]) new Object[5];`

Comment: Maybe I'm still confused, but shouldn't the type of array (String[],Integer[],Object[]) be determined when creating an instance of the class? For example, my goal for my SimpleQueue class is to be able to create an instance of the class and determine the type of array, thus the need for generics. Sometimes I might need a String[] array or some other time I might need an Integer[] array, but I don't want to code two different classes. Is that even possible without resorting to always using Object[] arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Object array `Object[] myQueue;` and cast the contents of it to `E` whenever you need to fetch values.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int startOfQueueIndex;
    private int numberOfElements;

    public MyQueue(int initialCapacity) {
        elements = new Object[initialCapacity);
        startOfQueueIndex = 0;
        numberOfElements = 0;
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (numberOfElements == elements.length)
            increaseElementArraySize();

        elements[(startOfQueueIndex + numberOfElements++) % elements.length] = e;
    }

    public E remove() {
        if (numberOfElements == 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        E element = (E)elements[startOfQueueIndex];

        startOfQueueIndex = (startOfQueueIndex + 1) % elements.length;

        return element;
    }

    // The rest of the methods go here ...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this please?

Comment: I've added an example (untested code !), I think it should clear things up.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot! My code is running smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

For a learning reference you may want to check out how `LinkedList` impelements the `Queue<E>` interface: Here's a [grepcode link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList) to the openjdk implementation.

`LinkedList` doesn't have an underlying array, instead it uses `Node` objects. This allows for easy allocation of new objects as you add them to the list.

For a reference how to cope with underlying array (ensure enough space etc.), you may want to see [ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.elementData%28int%29).

The code is well commented, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I did check it out but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new E instance, or an array of E, because E is an unknown type at compile time. but you could create a list of E.

```
private java.util.List<E> myQueue;
```

is the right way.

Comment: The question states the one of the requirements is not to use an `ArrayList`. I have a feeling this was intended for any `List` implementation.